# XmlSerializer cambiar ubicacion del archivo generado

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito cambiar la ubicación del archivo que me genera el **XmlSerializer** para poder guardarlo en alguna carpeta del servidor. El código con el que hago esto es el siguiente:

```
public void generateXml(String fileName, List<ElementToBuy> elementList)
    {
        string docXml;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ElementToBuy>));
            xml.Serialize(stream, elementList);
            docXml = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory +@"\"+ fileName;
        }
        sql = String.Empty;
        sql = "update buyOrder set detail = (select CONVERT(xml, BulkColumn) as BulkColumn from OpenRowset(Bulk '"+ docXml + "',Single_Blob) as x) where id_buyOrder = "+ buyOrderId;
        if (con.insert(sql))
        {
            File.Delete(docXml);
            MessageBox.Show("Pedido de provisión generado exitosamente");
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(docXml);
            MessageBox.Show("Eror al intentar generar el Pedido de provisión");
        }


        FrmBuyOrderReport frmBuyOrderReport = new FrmBuyOrderReport(buyOrder);
        frmBuyOrderReport.Show();

    }
```

El problema que tengo es que con este código puedo crear el archivo, pero no tengo los permisos necesarios del servidor para buscar el archivo y subirlo a la base de datos (SQL Server). Esta funcion crea el archivo, pero al momento de subirlo al servidor me da el siguiente error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'No se puede realizar la carga
>   masiva. El archivo "C:\Dropbox\Visual Studio
>   Projects\farmacia\Views\bin\Debug\19 - 8-3-2019.xml" no se puede
>   abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 3(El sistema no puede
>   encontrar la ruta especificada.).

En el caso de la aplicación instalada en las maquinas, no crea el archivo.
Como puedo hacer para reubicar el archivo en el servidor, o para obtener los permisos necesarios para poder ver el archivo desde el servidor, en la maquina donde esta instalada la aplicación?

Comment: Pero no le estas diciendo vos donde guardarlo?

Comment: no, no se como decirle donde guardarlo, por eso lo guarda automaticamente en esa carpeta. Cuando utilizo un localHost funciona bien, pero con el servidor remoto no funciona.

Comment: en filename le pasas el nombre del archivo. aca: xml.Serialize(stream, elementList); le decis donde guardarlo. aca: docXml = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory +@"\"+ fileName; le estas pasando otra ruta. Creo que en localhost anda, porque andaba de antes ;) si lo borras, muy probablemente deje de andar.. o anda pq esta parado siempre en esa carpeta.

Comment: esa linea la utilizo para traer el directorio donde se guarda el archivo, puedo asignarle valores (directorios diferentes) a System.Environment.CurrentDirectory ??

Comment: no, porque justamente es un directorio particular (el current). Pero nada impide que guardes en la ruta que vos quieras.

Comment: eso supongo, pero como le asigno un directorio diferente? eso es lo que no se como hacer

Comment: ya lo solucione!! si se puede asignar un valor diferente, de esta manera: **System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\ESD";**

Answer (score 0):

ya pude encontrar la solucion: asignarle un string con la direccion que necesito a **CurrentDirectory ** de esta manera

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\ESD";
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien más, gracias a gbianchi por orientarme.

Comment: Cambiar la variable de entorno no es una buena idea. Porque simplemente no hiciste docXml = @"C:\ESD\"+ fileName;?

Comment: porque no encuentro donde decirle al XmlSerializer que guarde el archivo en docXml.

Comment: TE voy a dejar una respuesta, porque no entendiste de donde viene tu ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces:

```
xml.Serialize(stream, elementList);
```

Le estas diciendo que serialice en stream tu xml. La ruta que esta usando, es la ruta que le diste al stream al generarlo, y esa ruta es:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
```

La que usaste para crearlo. Fijate que usaste fileName asi sin mas, y no le diste una ruta particular.
Por lo tanto, como solo tiene un nombre de archivo y no una ruta, usa la carpeta donde esta parado.

Si querias una nueva ruta, bastaba con decirle algo asi:

```
string nuevaruta = Path.Combine("c:\\acalarutaquequeres\\otracarpeta",fileName);
```

Y al hacer el stream, hacer:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(nuevaruta, FileMode.CreateNew))
```

Y despues docXml seria tambien nuevaruta

```
docXml = nuevaruta;
```

Con lo cual, podrias no usarla ;)